# SaxParserException Premature end of file

Tags: sax

I tried to write a code that will read and save to an xml file using sax, but I am new to this, so I keep getting the error in the title. Here is the code:

```
    public void readMoviesFromXML()
{
    ArrayList<Movie> lst = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("movies.xml");
        //I get the error at the line just above


        Node root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nodeList = root.getChildNodes();

        for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if(node instanceof Element)
            {
                Element element = (Element) node;

                Attr attr = element.getAttributeNode("moviename");
                String moviename = attr.getValue();

                String title = getNodeValue(element, "name");
                String rented = getNodeValue(element, "renttimes");

                Movie movie = new Movie(title, Integer.parseInt(rented));

                lst.add(movie);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mm.setMovieMap(lst);
}
```

The xml file is uninitialized and I fear that may be the problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did u try parsing using XDocument ?

Comment: I am not familiar with XML so I do not know what an XDocument is.

Comment: wait..let me give you a link on how to parse your XML document !

Comment: can you paste your XML here in the code so that I can parse it ?

Comment: It could be due to some errors in your XML. Putting your XML content here might help

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the following [link](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/xmldocument.html) for parsing your XML File . Once the document is parsed, you can always store it in a List or collection or whatever data structures.
Let me tell you that there are multiple ways to parse an XML document and some of the techniques have been shown in the example above

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end. It was giving me that error because the file was empty, so I initialized it with one element and it worked.